# Chrome blocks github download

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-chrome, github, antivirus

I'm publishing a small software on github. It consists of one exe and one dll written in .net. I packed both files in a zip and uploaded it to github.

If I try to download this zip in Google chrome the Browser blocks the download because it's harmfull. Of course it isn't. Any ideas how to fix? A software signing certificate is to expensive for me.

Edit: Of course I add the zip as a Release not as source Code

Comment: Just remove the .exe and .dll extensions before creating the archive and add them back after. Aside that, shouldn't this question be on [superuser](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: github is a source code repo, not a place to store exe and dll files. The idea is that you keep your actual source code in the repo and then you have a build process which compiles it and creates what's needed. No one knows what's in that exe and dll so the browser should block them, that part is working as intended.You might want to fix your actual issue, not its result.

Comment: You can add compiled releases to your repository.....So I think Im using it correct. https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-releases

Comment: Check with VirusTotal if there is any false positive and report that to the AV companies if any. Post at the forums at https://support.google.com/webmasters/community you can also try to report an error via chrome itself https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315 , but if it is a safe browsing problem, then the google chrome team is not responsible.

Comment: I have the same problem when attaching ZIP sources to Github issues.